# Installing Edimax 7611 Wifi Dongle?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-2, driver

I have an Edimax 7611 wifi dongle I'm trying to install. All the instructions I've found seem to require an existing internet connection to download updates and drivers. Is there a way to put the driver on a USB drive, copy it to the Pi, and install it from there? My Pi (a 2 B) has the latest stock version of Raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, simply go to the [Edimax download page for that device](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/de/download/undefined/for_home/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7611ulb),

[image: Ubuntu driver]

It's not hard to find, it was the third result when I googled [edimax 7611 driver](https://www.google.com/search?q=edimax%207611%20driver).

Then download on a Mac or PC, then as you say, copy to a USB stick and then stick it in your RPi and install.

As Raspbian is Debian based, then the Ubuntu driver *should* work.

---

It is unclear why:

1. You can't temporary stick an Ethernet cable in your Pi
2. What instructions you've read that state you need a connection to download updates and drivers. I mean, even my solution requires the internet, but not necessarily on the Pi itself.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I was looking for. I can connect an ethernet cable, it's just not convenient so I was looking for another solution.